# python, hydra, load variable from yaml to list

Tags: python, hydra

I got a below code:

```yaml
# settings.yaml

my_class:
  columns_id: ${oc.env:MY_LIST}
  all_columns: {"all_columns_as_str": ${oc.env:MY_LIST}}
```

where my variable is `MY_LIST=a,b,c`

then I got:

```py
# hydra_conf.py

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
  columns_id: list
  all_columns: dict[str, str]
```

and then I use it all like below:

```
# main.py
import hydra
from hydra_conf import MyClass

@hydra.main(config_path="settings", config_name="settings")
def main(cfg: MyClass) -> None:
    assert isinstance(cfg.columns_id, list)
    assert isinstance(cfg.all_columns, dict)
    assert cfg.all_columns['all_columns_as_str'] == 'a,b,c'
```

How I need to configure my `yml.file` or my `hydra_conf.py` file to load `columns_id` as `list` and `all_columns` as a `dict[str, str]`?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```yaml
# settings.yaml
defaults:
  - my_class_schema
  - _self_

columns_id: ${oc.decode:"[${oc.env:MY_LIST}]"}
all_columns:
  all_columns_as_str: ${oc.env:MY_LIST}
```

```py
# hydra_conf.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStoreWithProvider

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    columns_id: list[Any]
    all_columns: dict[str, str]

cs = ConfigStoreWithProvider(__file__)
cs.store("my_class_schema", MyClass)
```

```py
# main.py
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
from hydra_conf import MyClass

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="settings", version_base=None)
def main(cfg_: DictConfig) -> None:
    cfg: MyClass = OmegaConf.to_object(cfg_)
    assert isinstance(cfg, MyClass)
    assert isinstance(cfg.columns_id, list), f"{cfg.columns_id}"
    assert isinstance(cfg.all_columns, dict), f"{cfg.all_columns}"
    assert cfg.all_columns["all_columns_as_str"] == "a,b,c"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's how this works:

- Including `my_class_schema` in the defaults list means that your yaml file will be merged with the schema defined by `MyClass`. See the Hydra docs on [Structured Configs](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/intro/) (and specifically on using a [Structured Config Schema](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/schema/)) for more info about this.
- The string `"[${oc.env:MY_LIST}]"` results in `"[a,b,c]"` after the interpolation is resolved.
- The [`oc.decode`](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_resolvers.html#oc-decode) resolver parses the string `"[a,b,c]"`, resulting in `["a", "b", "c"]`.